# Adding API to Kong failed

Tags: docker, postman, kong

My docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

volumes:
    kong_data: {}

networks:
  kong-net:
services:
  kong-migrations:
    image: "${KONG_DOCKER_TAG:-kong:latest}"
    command: kong migrations bootstrap
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: ${KONG_PG_DATABASE:-kong}
      KONG_PG_HOST: db
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: ${KONG_PG_PASSWORD:-kong}
      KONG_PG_USER: ${KONG_PG_USER:-kong}
    links:
      - db:db
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: on-failure
  kong:
    image: "${KONG_DOCKER_TAG:-kong:latest}"
    user: "${KONG_USER:-root}"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      KONG_ADMIN_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_ADMIN_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
      KONG_ADMIN_LISTEN: '0.0.0.0:8001'
      KONG_CASSANDRA_CONTACT_POINTS: db
      KONG_DATABASE: postgres
      KONG_PG_DATABASE: ${KONG_PG_DATABASE:-kong}
      KONG_PG_HOST: db
      KONG_PG_PASSWORD: ${KONG_PG_PASSWORD:-kong}
      KONG_PG_USER: ${KONG_PG_USER:-kong}
      KONG_PROXY_ACCESS_LOG: /dev/stdout
      KONG_PROXY_ERROR_LOG: /dev/stderr
    networks:
      - kong-net
    ports:
      - "8000:8000/tcp"
      - "8001:8001/tcp"
      - "8443:8443/tcp"
      - "8444:8444/tcp"
    restart: on-failure
  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${KONG_PG_DATABASE:-kong}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${KONG_PG_PASSWORD:-kong}
      POSTGRES_USER: ${KONG_PG_USER:-kong}
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "${KONG_PG_USER:-kong}"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 3
    restart: on-failure
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    networks:
      - kong-net
    volumes:
      - kong_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  go-server:
    image: gobuild
    networks:
      - kong-net
    restart: on-failure
```

My docker containers

```
docker ps --format '{{.Names}}'
chapter11_go-server_1
chapter11_kong_1
chapter11_db_1
```

I am trying to make POST request to the Kong admin
API, which runs on port 8001. But it fails.

```
{
"name": "myapi",
"hosts": "server1",
"": "http://chapter11_go-server_1:3000",
"uris":["/api/v1"],
"strip_uri": true,
"preserve_host": false
}
```

Output

```
kong_1             | 172.21.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2019:10:36:58 +0000] "POST /apis HTTP/1.1" 404 23 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
kong_1             | 172.21.0.1 - - [29/Apr/2019:10:47:30 +0000] "POST /apis HTTP/1.1" 404 23 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.6.0"
```

How to find out if what is wrong with my POST request?

What is upstream_url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Kong 1.0.0 [changelog](https://github.com/Kong/kong/blob/1.0.0/CHANGELOG.md):

> The API entity and related concepts such as the /apis endpoint, are removed (deprecated since 0.13.0, March 2018). Use Routes and Services instead.

Since Kong 1.0 `/apis` endpoint is no longer available. Because of that you got 404 Not found response.

To add your API to Kong you have to use `/services` and `/routes`. This tutorial explains how to do it: [Configuring a Service](https://docs.konghq.com/1.1.x/getting-started/configuring-a-service/)